# Inserting a set list into SQL to pull use later with an IN query

Tags: sql, hive

I want to store a list of words in a single field in a column, and I then want to pull out in another select statement and then use this list with the `IN` keyword.

So I'm writing with python and

```
list_stems = ", ".join(["'"+stem['label']+"'" for stem in json_final[keyword]])
list_stems = "("+list_stems+")"
query = "INSERT INTO {table_name} (keyword, stem_list) VALUES ('{keyword}', {list_stems})".format(table_name= 'db.help', keyword=keyword, list_stems=list_stems)
spark.sql(query)
```

When I then look at what is written in to the field `stem_list` it is something beginning and ending with `{` and `}`. But no `(`and `)` that I can later pull out to perform as the `IN` query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, storing denormalized data in the column is a very bad idea.
Will be better to store each word in a separate row, if you want to use it in the future.

But. if we back to your example, [everything looks fine](https://onecompiler.com/python/3zq3vh4gf) for me:

```
keyword = "1"
list_stems = ", ".join(["abc", "cde"])
list_stems = "("+list_stems+")"
query = "INSERT INTO {table_name} (keyword, stem_list) VALUES ('{keyword}', {list_stems})".format(table_name= 'db.help', keyword=keyword, list_stems=list_stems)
print(query)
```